# realPath for MockHttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, realpath

I am writing a Spring based Test case for my Spring Controller, in my controller we are using  like this "request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/myFolderName");"
Its working fine for normal requests, but for unit test cases like MockHttpServletRequest it is the above method call is giving null. how can i get realPath for MockHttpServletRequest.

Thanks,
Praneeth.

Comment: Split the statement up into several smaller ones so you can see which part is causing the NPE.  Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

By default `MockHttpServletRequest` acts as if root webapp folder is a classpath, therefore you should be able to use `getRealPath()` for classpath resources.

Alternatively, you can supply `MockHttpServletRequest` with `MockServletContext`, and `MockServletContext` can be configured with specific root folder for `getRealPath()`, etc.